# How to change the default button behaviour in a QDialog

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qdialog

I read that `QDialog` has as default all its objects set as default. For example if I add a `QPushButton`:

```
pushButton.setDefault(True)   
pushButton.setAutoDefaul(True)
```

I know that I can set each one as `False`, but is there a way of avoiding `QDialog` setting all its objects as default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, setting the default to `False` for all the buttons *will have no affect*. If no button has been set as the default, the dialog will just [choose one automatically](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#default-prop) - so there will *always* be a default, no matter what you do.

You can change this behaviour by overriding the dialog's `keyPressEvent`:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.Cancel):
        self.reject()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

This completely overrides the default-button behaviour, but retains cancellation of the dialog when e.g. <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed. If you don't want that either, just call `event.ignore()`, which will allow all keypress events to propagate to the current focus-widget. Thus, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> when a button or line-edit has the focus will still activate it as normal. The default-button mechanism only comes into play when some other widget has the focus but does not swallow the keypress event (e.g. when pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> in a line-edit).

Comment: This works, but it absorbs all Return presses. What do I do if I have LineEdits or other input elements in the dialog that need Returns?

Comment: I have now added a simplified solution which should be easier to work with.